# OGG-01224 TCP/IP error 113 (No route to host), endpoint: gg_target:7809

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I have two servers, where goldenGate manager is running fine. But while doing extract I am getting OGG-01224  TCP/IP error 113 (No route to host), endpoint: gg_target:7809 error.

I tried giving ip address as well  but no luck.
both the servers are password less ssh enabled

Comment: Can you ping the gg_target server from the source? double check the port that manger is running on the target server, to make sure it's running on 7809. Nick

Answer (score 0):

This generally is caused by an firewall on your target machine. Please use

```
chkconfig –level 235 iptables off
```

or

```
service iptables stop.
```